# How do I use URL struct in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm building an app which displays a PDF file, however I need help with Swift language. I'm coming from Flutter/Dart environment and I do not know how this language works.

I need to convert a String to URL in Swift, does anyone know how I can do that? I'm building the app with MVVM architecture pattern. I would like my ViewModel to fetch an URL as a String from my View. Once I do that, Xcode tells me that the class doesn't have any initializers. How do I solve that?

[image: Image 1]

### Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class DeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var url: URL
    
    func fetchUrl(urlString: String) {
        self.url = URL(string: urlString)
    }
}
```

Comment: To learn the basics of Swift such as creating initialisers, handling optionals and more may I suggest your read the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) book.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too basic and this is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing these two errors for two different reasons, lets look at them one by one.

### Class 'DeedViewModel' has no initializers

This error occurs because of this line:

> var url: URL

What it means is that you have declared a variable called url of type `URL`, *but you have not given it a value*.

You can give this variable a value in - at least - two ways:

1. Give it a default value like so for instance:

`var url: URL = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!` (which can be shortened to `var url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com)!` as the compiler can infer that this is a URL). We'll get back to the `!` in just a second as this is not the right way to do things.

2. Make an `init` method and pass in a `URL` there. This can look like so:

```
init(url: URL) {
    self.url = url
}
```

### Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL'

This error occurs because - as @raja-kishan mentions - the initializer for URL that takes a `String` as input can return an *optional* value, which makes sense when you think about it.

For instance, what if you try to create a URL like so:

`var url = URL(string: "in no way am I a URL")`

That should not work I hope you agree :)

Now, in your code you have declared

`var url: URL`

Meaning: I expect a valid URL here.

and then you try to assign an optional URL value to that here:

```
func fetchUrl(urlString: String) {
    self.url = URL(string: urlString)
}
```

And that fails, which the compiler informs you about in its own special way.

So, as Raja suggests, the safest is to declare your `url` as an optional `URL?`. That way you don't have to initialise it.

That also means that you have to unwrap your `url` before you try to use it...but that is for the best right? I mean, you probably wouldn't want to work with an invalid url in the first place.

So when you need to work with your `url` you need to do this first:

```
if let url = url {
    //you now have a valid url to work with
}
```

or

```
guard let url = url else { 
    no valid url exists, handle that here
}
//here it is safe to work with your url
```

### A Note on `!`

You *could* fall for the temptation and force unwrap your URL as I have done in my example above.

`var url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com)!`

Force unwrapping is *almost never* the right way to go in a Swift program.  Especially not when you are working with user input. If you try to force unwrap a variable, and then use it and it fails, your app will crash.

Instead, use `if let` or `guard` to safely unwrap your optional variable. It may seem length and convoluted at first but when you get used to it it is one of the best parts of Swift I think. Plus...the alternative - a crashed app - is worse :)

Comment: Your answer is good for the most part, but you need to add a giant, neon red warning sign around the suggestion of using the `!` force unwrap operator. I tell new Swift developers to call this the "crash if nil" operator, because that's what it does. The OP stated that they are collecting an URL string from a user. Thus the URL is unverified user data. If you then try to force-unwrap the result of `URL(string:)` the app will crash any time the user enters an invalid URL string.

Comment: @DuncanC you are absolutely right, I was in a bit of a hurry writing my answer. I'll swing back and refine that part.

Comment: @DuncanC There we go, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Excellent. (Voted)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `var url: URL` as an optional, because of `URL(string:)` return optional URL.

Correct model:

```
class DeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var url: URL?
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        self.url = URL(string: urlString)
    }
    
    func fetchUrl(urlString: String) -> URL? {
        self.url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Raja is a little misleading too.

You need the url initialized in the init which is a function but not called the way you called it.

Instead of this

```
func fetchUrl(urlString: String) {
    self.url = URL(string: urlString)   
}
```

You need

```
init(urlString: String) {
    self.url = URL(string: urlString)
}
```